# Use image as radio button on Contact Form 7 but not receiving image in mail

Tags: wordpress, forms, function, contact-form-7

I used this code below which is very useful in wordpress function.php for contact form 7 to select images as checkbox but its not receiving in email, please help me in this matter, thanks

## Here is the code

```
function add_shortcode_imageradio() {
    wpcf7_add_shortcode( 'imageradio', 'imageradio_handler', true );
}
add_action( 'wpcf7_init', 'add_shortcode_imageradio' );

function imageradio_handler( $tag ){
    $tag = new WPCF7_FormTag( $tag );

    $atts = array(
        'type' => 'radio',
        'name' => $tag->name,
        'list' => $tag->name . '-options' );

    $input = sprintf(
        '<input %s />',
        wpcf7_format_atts( $atts ) );
        $datalist = '';
        $datalist .= '<div class="imgradio">';
        foreach ( $tag->values as $val ) {
        list($radiovalue,$imagepath) = explode("!", $val
    );

    $datalist .= sprintf(
     '<label><input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s" class="hideradio" /><img src="%s"></label>', $tag->name, $radiovalue, $imagepath 
    );

    }
    $datalist .= '</div>';

    return $datalist;
}
```

Here is the page I am working on:
https://www.commforceintl.com/lost-and-found-english/

Comment: Plz Share your code instead of a link so that we can check the problem. How do you call this field in your email template?

Comment: gael I have edited my above post with the code and output link your help will be very beneficial thanks